# Android SQLITE query slow on large number of rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 tables and the query I need runs very slow.
For exemplification, I show two sample tables with the relevant fields.

```
Table MAIN
      MAIN.USERID text
      MAIN.LOGGED_USERID text
      MAIN.other text fields not relevant to query
Index on USERID, LOGGED_USERID

Table LOGS
      LOGS.CREATED int
      LOGS.USERID text
      LOGS.LOGGED_USERID text
      LOGS.TYPE int

Index on USERID,LOGGED_USERID,TYPE
```

I need to get the most recent date of a USER/LOGGED_USER from the LOGS table. The query I need to run is similar to:

```
Select m.some fields,
   (Select l.CREATED 
    from LOGS l 
    where l.USERID=u.USERID and l.LOGGED_USERID=m.LOGGED_USERID and TYPE=1 
    order by l.CREATED desc limit 1) as LAST_DATE
from MAIN m
WHERE some fields not relevant and an EXIST command from other table
ORDER BY some fields not relevant
```

While the query runs fine for a limited number of rows, when having 150.000 rows on each table, the query actually never seems to finish, or at least I haven't waited that long for it. The performance drop comes from the LAST_DATE query, as without it, it's instant
Probably the indexes I have are not used?

Comment: `... WHERE some fields not relevant...` these "not relevant" fields should be indexed too. Main rule for indexing: `Index all the JOIN and the WHERE columns`.

Comment: Might need to check without the sub-query. Replace it by a join if you can (I see `u.USERID` but this might be `m.USERID`) because it will be executed for every row.

Comment: Without the LAST_DATE query, everything works fast. With the LAST_DATE query, even without any WHERE on main query or ORDER, the query seem to run for a long time. That is why I have not included the WHERE

Comment: @AxelH you are right, it's m. I don't know how I could replace it with a join considering that I need the most recent CREATED value.

Comment: Check the query I have wrote. Note sure of the notation but the inner query should be correct (using group by). But you might need to update the query to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution execute the sub-query for each row.

Using a join, this will be executed only once then join both tables.

Here is the query to get the last created LOGS per user_id and logger_userid

```
Select max(CREATED), LOGGED_USERID, USERID
       from LOGS l 
       where TYPE=1 
       group by LOGGED_USERID, USERID
```

And to use it in a join, simply use an alias :

```
Select m.some fields,
   l.CREATED as LAST_DATE
   from MAIN m
   inner join (Select max(CREATED), LOGGED_USERID, USERID
       from LOGS l 
       where TYPE=1 
       group by LOGGED_USERID, USERID
   ) l on l.USERID = M.USERID ANd l.LOGGED_USERID = M.LOGGED_USERID.
```

> NOTE : I am note sure of SQLite notation, I've worked on Sybase for too long ..

This still needs the where and order condition of course, this is just to correct the `select .. from ...` part

Comment: I was not aware that it's possible on sqlite to have a query as inner join. Using this solution makes my result return after 2-3 seconds. So wow. Thanks a lot. I still need to check the accuracy of the returned info, but it looks promising! Thank you.

Comment: @alin Might have issues with **inner** join, you might need a left or right join depending on your needs.

Comment: I should have in LOGS a record for each MAIN. But what if on LOGS I don't have any entry? Maybe I should use a RIGHT join, so that the rows from MAIN are always returned and the CREATED can be null?

Comment: Then it it is a left join, all the row of the left table will be there with null for the right table. (`from left_table join right_table`)

Answer (score -1):

As you do not show your code, I think you are taking too much work from the UI thread. So by taking this assumption you should use Loaders. In your case **Cursor Loaders**. Loaders basically run on separate thread and avoids slow UI.
See the link of Loaders explained:
[Loaders in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The call is made in a AsyncTask. Even so, after running the query on my PC, after pulling the database and using a GUI for sqlite, it still fails to run.

Comment: For querying data in Sqlite, the best pattern in Android is by using CursorLoader instead of Asycktask.